# Managing duplicates when sorting by character order in string

Tags: python

I am trying to solve through a challenge where I have to reorder the letters in string s in the order it appears on string t.  For example:

```
For s = "weather" and t = "therapyw", the output should be
sortByString(s, t) = "theeraw";

For s = "good" and t = "odg", the output should be
sortByString(s, t) = "oodg".
```

This is my code:

```
def sortByString(s, t):

    s_list = list(s)
    t_list = list(t)
    output = []

    for i in range(len(t_list)):
        if t_list[i] in s_list:
            output.insert(i, t_list[i])

    return ''.join(output)
```

It works for all cases except if the same letter exists more than once.

```
s: "weather"
t: "therapyw"
Output:
"theraw"
Expected Output:
"theeraw"
```

How can I handle this situation in my code above?  What am I missing?  I appreciate all help but instead of just blurting out the answer, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that it only adds one copy of each character in `t` to `output`, regardless of how many times it occurs in `s`. You can work around that by looping over the `count` of that character in `s` and appending to `output` for each count:

```
def sortByString(s, t):

    s_list = list(s)
    t_list = list(t)
    output = []

    for i in range(len(t_list)):
        for _ in range(s_list.count(t_list[i])):
            output.append(t_list[i])

    return ''.join(output)

print(sortByString('weather',"therapyw"))
print(sortByString('good',"odg"))
```

Output:

```
theeraw
oodg
```

You can simplify the loop by just adding copies of a list with the current character according to the count of the character in `s`:

```
for c in t_list:
    output = output + [c] * s_list.count(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easy way

Use enumerate and turn your string into a dict

```
def sortByString(s, t):

    s_list = list(s)
    t_list = list(t)

    orderdict = {char: index for index, char in enumerate(t_list)}
    output = sorted(list('weather'),key=orderdict.get)

    return ''.join(output)
```

This will allow repeated values

- Example

```
>>> sortByString('weather',"therapyw")
'theeraw'
```

### Modification to OP's code

Just add the element number of times it appear in `s` to the `output`

```py
def sortByString(s,t):
     s_list = list(s)
     t_list = list(t)
     output = []
     for i in range(len(t_list)):
             if t_list[i] in s_list:
                     output.append(t_list[i]*s_list.count(t_list[i]))
     return ''.join(output)
```

- output

```
>>> sortByString('weather',"therapyw")
'theeraw'
```

Comment: "I appreciate all help but instead of just blurting out the answer, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong"

Comment: @oo92 Let's take your second example in that `'e'` is only checked once as it is appear in `t` only once while iterating through it.

Comment: What you can do is in the if block find the count of the element and add that many times to it also use `append` instead of `insert`

Comment: @oo92 I've updated my answer, Does this make things clear?

Answer (score 0):

2 steps:

a. create a sorted list of characters in s and their order in t using index()

b. use zip(* to extract the sorted list of characters

```
s = "weather"
t = "therapy"

a = sorted([(t.index(c),c) for c in s])
b = ''.join(list(zip(*a))[1])

print(b)
```

Output:

```
theeraw
```